# Article omission regarding specific theories in science

Tags: definite-article, zero-article

I am writing a paper which involves references to different theories.

I wonder if you should use an article before, for example "social exchange theory" or not. I searched for it on Google Books and found some publications where the article is omitted and some where it is used.

Comment: I hadn't heard of *[the] social exchange theory* before seeing it here, but [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=social+exchange+theory%2Cthe+social+exchange+theory&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csocial%20exchange%20theory%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20social%20exchange%20theory%3B%2Cc0) clearly suggests it doesn't usually merit the ("status-enhancing"?) definite article. Nor does it usually get referenced (as per Darwin's *theory of evolution*) using the format *the theory of social exchange*.

Comment: (The name makes me think of ***Transactional Analysis*** (TA) - a psychoanalytic theory that I *have* heard of.)

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that "theory" can mean different things in different contexts. It can be used to refer to both a very specific and singular idea or explanation (for example: the theory of general relativity), or it can refer to a broad category of thought or study (for example: game theory).

In this case, "social exchange theory" appears to be a case of the latter usage of "theory", referring to a broad category of study, so you would not modify it with "the" in this case.

It can also be said that using "the" in front a theory makes it more definitive, so usage of "the" might be reserved for theories which reach a certain level of acceptance within a given scholarly or scientific community.